# Option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" was replaced by configuration "setupFilesAfterEnv", which supports multiple paths

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

> Option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" was replaced by configuration "setupFilesAfterEnv", which supports multiple paths.
>
> Please update your configuration.

I found this exact question here: [setupTestFrameworkScriptFile is not supported error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043517/setuptestframeworkscriptfile-is-not-supported-error)

I renamed my `jest.config.js` to `setUpTests.js` however that did not remove the deprecated error warning.

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next -p 7777",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next -p 7777",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch --no-cache",
  "test-win": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& jest --watch"
}
```

```
"@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
"@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
"jest": "^24.1.0"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Jest` used to have a config option called `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`...

...but it was deprecated in favor of the newer [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) in [PR #7119](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/7119) which shipped with [version 24.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2400).

Since you are using `Jest` ^v24.1.0 you will need to use `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

Just find where `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is used in your `Jest` config, rename it to `setupFilesAfterEnv`, and put the single file it used to point to in an array and you should be good to go.

Example, change this `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: './setup.js',
  ...
}
```

...to this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setup.js'],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Bless you, sir!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **create-react-app**, change the key name at `package.json` file

from

```
  "jest": {
    // ...
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js",
```

to

```
  "jest": {
    // ...
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"],
```

Comment: So, you advice to replace `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` with `setupFilesAfterEnv` and put path into `[]` just like the accepted answer...

Comment: Bless you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

After I changed my file name from setupTests.js to setup.tests.js it worked. Maybe the dir path name did not match. Make sure you check that!

Answer (score 0):

In my case in 'jest.config.js' I had

> setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts']

correctly referencing 'setup-jest.ts' in <rootDir>.
After renaming the file itself and the reference to it from

```
setup-jest.ts
```

to

```
setupJest.js
```

the error message vanished. Weird. Seems as if the hyphen in the file-name or being the same as in 'node_modules.jest-reset-angular.setup-jest.js' was the culprit.
Using Angular 13 and Jest (in package.json):

"jest": "^28.1.0",

"jest-preset-angular": "^12.1.0",

I'm on Lubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Jest message is not mantained anymore: https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-expect-message/issues

So I suggest using:

```
const msg = '... my message...'
expect({msg, result}).toEqual({msg, result: expected})
```

From https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3293

Or alternatively

```
function expectToBeTrue(result: any, message: string){
    return expect({message, result}).toBe({message, result: true})
}


expectToBeTrue(compute() == 1, "Oh no compute should return 1!")
```