# Configure jest timeout once for all tests

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

According to the docs one can increase the default async timeout from 5000ms using the  [jest-object](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object)

More specifically, by using the [jestsettimeouttimeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout)

The issue I am facing is I am running a series of tests against an API that is very slow, 5-15 second response times, configuring this jest object at the top of each test is painfully annoying.

Is it possible to declare these settings once before all test files are run?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK, putting bits together:

- [Option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" was replaced by configuration "setupFilesAfterEnv", which supports multiple paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752673/option-setuptestframeworkscriptfile-was-replaced-by-configuration-setupfilesa#answer-55803809)
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdisableautomock

The Jest search box doesn't actually return anything when you search for: setupFilesAfterEnv

And docs talk about: setupTestFrameworkScriptFile (which also doesn't return anything on the search:/ )

Anyway, the docs leave you scratching your head but this works:

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setup.js'],
```

setup.js:

```
jest.setTimeout(10000); // in milliseconds
```

The jest folks should make it easier to find this information.

Comment: If someone stumbles across this post. The jest folks added a new config option called [`testTimeout`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testtimeout-number) which would do the same. :)

Comment: FYI, I was looking for something I could use for a whole suite that would not affect other suites (in this case, it was an e2e suite whose tests took much longer to run than unit tests). I've now confirmed that using `jest.setTimeout(n)` is in fact per-suite and will not affect your other suites.

Answer (score 42):

Jest offers a [`testTimeout`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testtimeout-number) configuration option you can add to your `package.json`:

```json
  "jest": {
    "testTimeout": 15000,
  }
```

Comment: Hack!. You need to delete comma when single object has been.

Answer (score 27):

Use [testTimeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testtimeout-number). In your`jest.config.js` (or similar), add the following:

```
const SECONDS = 1000;

module.exports = {
  testTimeout: 60 * SECONDS
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with `react` and initializing you app using `create-react-app`, then under your `src/` directory you should have a file named `setupTests.js`. Here you can setup a global timeout for all of your tests just by insert this line after the import statement for `@testing-libary`

```
jest.setTimeout(15000); // in milliseconds
```